# UIApplication does not exist in this context error Xamarin Forms upgrade to unified API

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I have upgraded my Xamarin forms application to use the new unified API

I have followed the instructions and all went well until the code below which was not changed, and has been the same since it was generated by the project template when I started this last week

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Newtest.iOS
{
    public class Application
    {
        // This is the main entry point of the application.
        static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            // if you want to use a different Application Delegate class from "AppDelegate"
            // you can specify it here.
            UIApplication.Main (args, null, "AppDelegate");
        }
    }
}
```

The error is:

> UIApplication does not exist in this context.

I know there has been a lot of renaming as part of the unified API but I cant see anything about this error

I even tried to create a new application after the update to see if the project template generated different code for Main.cs in my IOS app but it didnt

Is there somewhere I can get updated templates from? I am using Xamarin Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the Unified API, [UIApplication](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=T%3AUIKit.UIApplication) is in the UIKit namespace.  You need to add

```
using UIKit;
```

Comment: Hello Jason, do you have any idea for the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787857/viewcontroller-to-viewcontroller-segue-in-xamarin